# Heroku Precompiling Assets Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku, asset-pipeline

My app is suddenly not working after an update. Not sure what's going wrong. Basically, when I push to heroku, I get these errors:

```
Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
```

And a little higher up:

```
   rake aborted!
   Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 19073, col: 9, pos: 605247)
   Error
   at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20121211-811-1z5vum.js:1720:22)
   at js_error (/tmp/execjs20121211-811-1z5vum.js:1728:15)
   at croak (/tmp/execjs20121211-811-1z5vum.js:2189:17)
   at token_error (/tmp/execjs20121211-811-1z5vum.js:2196:17)
   at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20121211-811-1z5vum.js:2202:17)
   at /tmp/execjs20121211-811-1z5vum.js:2580:17
   at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20121211-811-1z5vum.js:2665:27)
   at expr_op (/tmp/execjs20121211-811-1z5vum.js:2685:45)
   at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20121211-811-1z5vum.js:2692:24)
   at maybe_conditional (/tmp/execjs20121211-811-1z5vum.js:2696:28)
```

When I actually load up the site ("We're sorry, but something went wrong"), and look at the heroku logs, I get this:

```
Load path: /app
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)):
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kreon' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:1
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <meta name="google-site-verification" content="idIPkgRBikSL9PCS4rVkkZfRjxYbPxNbyF6tVymBWbc" />
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-11T23:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

(Kreon is an additional font I added a while back that's been working fine. custom.css.scss is my main css file, and the first line is where I import bootstrap in a way that hasn't changed and has worked forever).

I searched for how to deal with the "File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap" error, and landed on [this discussion](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/759) and checked out the [relevant heroku troubleshoot page](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting), but changing assets.compile to true in my production.rb file led to the heroku push errors above, and the troubleshoot page didn't seem to have much relevant to my specific problem. Not really sure what's going on here, so I'm just going to put a bunch of possibly relevant code below.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'googlecharts', :require => "gchart"
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
end

group :test do 
    gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1'
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
end

gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.4'
  gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'roadie'
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'foreman'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

production.rb

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, 
  # and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

The line that's really throwing me is this one in my heroku push log:

```
Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 19073, col: 9, pos: 605247)
```

The issue, is I have no idea what file to look in for this troublesome ">". Any ideas how to read that line/col/pos nomenclature to find the actual offending code snippet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STart with line 1 of `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss` and look for an errant `>`.
Also look to make sure that application.scss is what you expect.

Also just rename `custom.css.scss` to just`custom.scss` Heck, that may do it.

Comment: So actually, the problem seems to have been that when I changed some .js files to js.coffee files, git kept the .js versions as well, and having identical files with different extensions was causing a problem. Renaming and trying to push custom.whatever pointed that out, and when I removed the redundant files, everything worked. So thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: no problem. wait until you have bigger issues with asset precompile too, then the fun really starts man!

Comment: yep, same issue here and had a blast @pjammer

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the terminal:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace
```

Better than trying to push on heroku.

I just had the same errors.
The problem was:

- the config.secret_key of devise was commented
- syntax_error in a javascript file ( an "of" instead of an "in" in a for loop)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me as well, 
"Precompiling assets failed." while pushing to heroku, 
In my development environment I had an error in my css: 
"......... 
   cursor: pointer 
    color: #808080;"

missing the ";" after the "pointer",
the development environment didn't mind the error,
but Heroku's PreCompile task did.

Some other Problems might be caused by duplicate named file, with "css" and "css.scss" suffixes.