# heroku Uglifier::Error: Name expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

After try to deploy a simple rails test app into heroku, in the terminal poped up this

> Uglifier::Error: Name expected

in the middle of the assets compilation.
i've searched and i did not find anything related to this, so someone ahs any idea this name expected is about?

```
remote:        I, [2018-04-27T20:10:19.341334 #1686]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_171697f13e39a581026e766b205b8f86/public/assets/white-774a5ae6a58216b107623782ce2e1820ebb64f9d294cad32e132c086866f3dd2.png

remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Uglifier::Error: Name expected
remote:        
/tmp/build_171697f13e39a5810263766b205b8f86/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.4/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
```

Comment: Please provide more context or no one is going to be able to help you. All we know right now is that compliation of an asset failed. but without any knowledge of your application structure or its assets we will not be able to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your asset pre-compilation works locally

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

If there are any errors that should help you find where they are happening.

Also see possible duplicate of [Heroku Precompiling Assets Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830392/heroku-precompiling-assets-failed#13831152)

Comment: thank you, worked but why did not worked on heroku on the first time? seems a problem with heroku

Comment: when you say "it worked" what worked? Did running command locally tell you anything or give any errors?  It's possible pre compile works locally but if you commit precompiled assets (which you shouldn't) then Heroku won't precompile them. That may be why "it worked"

Comment: lacostenycoder that's what happened. locally everything is fine i commited and pushed to heroku. so, iĺl remove the pre compiled assets and try again to check

Comment: if you remove locally compiled assets, you will probably get error again on heroku. see the answer I posted link to

Comment: i checked everything, if it was the css or the js mistaken error it did not appear on the images part of compiling. anyway thank you lacostenycoder for your help