# Precompiling assets failed while deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, environment-variables

I am having an issue trying to deploy an old rails application. Since its old, I know there are tons of things that could fail, and I have been fixing one by one since this morning, but now I am stuck with something that other people also posted, but didn’t work for me so far.
I have tried [Heroku Precompiling Assets Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830392/heroku-precompiling-assets-failed)
and went through https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline, but still failing.

I will reproduce the logs here:

```
git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 2150, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2150/2150), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (770/770), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2150/2150), 4.08 MiB | 134.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2150 (delta 1315), reused 2125 (delta 1300), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 1.17.3
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.6
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.17.3
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 BUNDLE_GLOBAL_PATH_APPENDS_RUBY_SCOPE=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
remote:        Fetching rake 13.0.3
remote:        Installing rake 13.0.3
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.7
remote:        Fetching multi_json 1.15.0
remote:        Fetching minitest 4.7.5
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.15.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.7
remote:        Installing minitest 4.7.5
remote:        Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 0.3.59
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing tzinfo 0.3.59
remote:        Fetching builder 3.1.4
remote:        Installing builder 3.1.4
remote:        Fetching erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching rack 1.5.5
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing rack 1.5.5
remote:        Fetching mime-types 1.25.1
remote:        Installing mime-types 1.25.1
remote:        Fetching polyglot 0.3.5
remote:        Fetching activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.4
remote:        Installing activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.4
remote:        Installing polyglot 0.3.5
remote:        Fetching arel 4.0.2
remote:        Fetching bcrypt 3.1.16
remote:        Installing arel 4.0.2
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.16 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching sass 3.2.19
remote:        Installing sass 3.2.19
remote:        Using bundler 1.17.3
remote:        Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Fetching execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching thor 1.0.1
remote:        Installing thor 1.0.1
remote:        Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Fetching hike 1.2.3
remote:        Installing hike 1.2.3
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.5.4
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.5.4 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching pg 1.2.3
remote:        Installing pg 1.2.3 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Fetching rdoc 6.3.0
remote:        Installing rdoc 6.3.0
remote:        Fetching temple 0.8.2
remote:        Installing temple 0.8.2
remote:        Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Fetching i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Installing i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Fetching rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Fetching warden 1.2.7
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.7
remote:        Fetching treetop 1.4.15
remote:        Installing treetop 1.4.15
remote:        Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Fetching uglifier 4.2.0
remote:        Installing uglifier 4.2.0
remote:        Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.0.3.0
remote:        Installing bootstrap-sass 3.0.3.0
remote:        Fetching bcrypt-ruby 3.1.5
remote:        Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.1.5
remote:        Fetching sprockets 2.12.5
remote:        Installing sprockets 2.12.5
remote:        Fetching sdoc 2.0.3
remote:        Installing sdoc 2.0.3
remote:        Fetching slim 3.0.9
remote:        Installing slim 3.0.9
remote:        Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Fetching activesupport 4.0.0
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching mail 2.5.5
remote:        Installing mail 2.5.5
remote:        Fetching actionpack 4.0.0
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching activemodel 4.0.0
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 1.5.3
remote:        Installing jbuilder 1.5.3
remote:        Fetching actionmailer 4.0.0
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching railties 4.0.0
remote:        Installing railties 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 2.0.1
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.0.1
remote:        Fetching activerecord 4.0.0
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching puma 5.1.1
remote:        Installing puma 5.1.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Fetching devise 3.0.4
remote:        Installing devise 3.0.4
remote:        Fetching font-awesome-rails 4.7.0.5
remote:        Installing font-awesome-rails 4.7.0.5
remote:        Fetching jquery-rails 3.1.5
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 3.1.5
remote:        Fetching sass-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Installing sass-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Fetching slim-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Installing slim-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Fetching rails 4.0.0
remote:        Installing rails 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching devise_security_extension 0.10.0
remote:        Installing devise_security_extension 0.10.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 57 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Post-install message from bcrypt-ruby:
remote:        
remote:        #######################################################
remote:        
remote:        The bcrypt-ruby gem has changed its name to just bcrypt.  Instead of
remote:        installing `bcrypt-ruby`, you should install `bcrypt`.  Please update your
remote:        dependencies accordingly.
remote:        
remote:        #######################################################
remote:        
remote:        Bundle completed (24.02s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
remote: -----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:82: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        SystemStackError: stack level too deep
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:157:in `local_cache_key'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:94:in `middleware'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:64:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_62ef82ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to myaccount.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/myaccount.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myaccount.git'
```

GEMFILE:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem "rails", "4.0.0"

# Bundler version compatible with Ruby 2.0 and onwards

gem "bundler", "1.17.3"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3"    #gem to use in development-test environment
end

group :production do
  gem "pg"         #gem to use in production environment
  gem "rails_12factor"
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem "sass-rails", "~> 4.0.0"

#gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.0.3.0"

gem "font-awesome-rails"

# gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.3.1'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem "uglifier", ">= 1.3.0"

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem "coffee-rails", "~> 4.0.0"

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem "slim-rails"

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem "jquery-rails"

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem "turbolinks"

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem "jbuilder", "~> 1.2"

gem "devise", "~> 3.0.0"

gem "devise_security_extension"

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem "sdoc", require: false
end

#gem 'airbrake'

gem "puma"

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Aplication.rb

```
require File.expand_path("../boot", __FILE__)

require "rails/all"
require "slim"
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Snedda
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    config.i18n.default_locale = :is

    config.sass.load_paths << File.expand_path("../../lib/assets/stylesheets/")
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

    config.assets.precompile += [
      "home.css",
      "home.js",
    ]
  end
end
```

I know some people advice to remote sqlite3 since its not supported by heroku, but that’s the reason why I set it up to the development group.

Hope you can see something that I don't!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need to use rails 4.0.0? Can you at least upgrade to 4.0.13? It looks like you've got some gem conflicts with activesupport, in any case. You might need to downgrade some other gems. Have you tried running the asset pre compile on your local machine with a fresh gemset?

Comment: it seems that either I modify the rails version, or the gems. In any case, it would trigger some other conflicts apparently. I thought there was maybe a different turnover. What would be the benefit on upgrading Rails btw?

Comment: The lowest numbered version of any sequence will have bugs in it, as newer minor versions should have them fixed. The 4.0.13 should be completely compatible with 4.0.0 ... It probably won't help, but it might

Comment: Can you not use original gemfile ? Also using a recent Ruby version on an old rails app may also break. I think the current Ruby version for Rails 4.0 was 1.9.3

Comment: I am using ruby version 2.5.1. How is that about not using original gemfile?

Comment: I know from experience that rails 3 is on the ruby 1.9 to 2.0 border. Rails 4 is happy with newer versions

Answer (score 0):

Heroku tries to build assets using ruby 2.6.0, but you have rails 4.0 that is not compatible.
To make everything work you have to:

- upgrade rails (4.0.13 -> 4.1.16 -> 4.2.11.3 -> 5.0.7.2 -> 5.1.7)
- your own code to be compatible with fresh rubies (2.4 and then 2.6)
- make sure that your app works locally with 2.6

Other way is to replace heroku with a conventional vps where you can install an old ruby and use deprecated rails. But this is not recommended due to security concerns, because 4.0 and old gems have vulnerabilities.